# jQuery remove() is not working properly

Tags: jquery, html

I have a listing as below;

```
<ul id="toDB">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

I'm deleteing `<li>` items using the following jquery function;

```
$('#toDB > li').click(function(){
   $(this).remove(); //I also tried with detach();
});
```

After deleting certain items, I'm storing the remaining items in a jQuery variable which  I'm then saving to a database.

```
var sendThis = $('#toDB').html();
```

After retrieving the items from the database, I still see the deleted items in the listing.   Are there any mistakes in my code?

**Update:**

My code is working well and I can see in the Chrome Developer Tool that items are removing. But the deleted items are appearing again after retrieving the items from the database.

Please help me fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: And you're updating `sendThis` inside the click function to get the changed HTML after every click, like [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NYkRX/2/)

Comment: I do have save button, so after sorting the listing, saving to the varibale sendThis will happen when I clikng the save button.

Comment: Your code works as-is (http://jsfiddle.net/nABTb/). Problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, it is working in the browser, I can see in the inspect element its removing. But after saving to the database and retreiving  its camong back

Comment: Are you actually deleting the items from your database?

Comment: No i'm deleting the item in the browser itself, then i;m sending the remaining to the database

Comment: In that case, you need to delete the items which didn't get sent. Calling `.remove()` just removes the item(s) from the DOM, it has no affinity with the database

Comment: I'm testing only with adding to the Databse not updating or editing. According to the code and the way it works in the browser only the remaining items should go to the database through the variable. 

I also tried by alerting the remainign item before send to the database. In that case I see items are deleted.

Comment: If you don't remove any records from the database, why would you expect them not to show up?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct db entry?  If it alerts properly before saving it to your db, either you save code is wrong or you're looking at the wrong thing

Answer (score 0):

Well this is bizzare....it should work. Depending on the part of the code you have shared, the removal is working with your code already.

Are you sure that before sending it to the DB, the latest state of the element is holding up or something else is being passed to the DB.

Before sending the file to the DB, just check if the list is holding the correct values that you require.

`alert($('#toDB').html());`

Answer (score 0):

It might depend also as to at what level are you deleting the `li` tags.
Though there is NOTHING bassically wrong with you jQuery lines... I trust

```
   $('li','#toDB').click(function(){
   $(this).remove(); 
});
```

than....

```
$('#toDB > li').click(function(){
   $(this).remove(); 
});
```

Though they Serve the same purpose if am not wrong....

You should also NOTE that jQuery does NOT handle `click(function(){})`  automatically for Dynamically loaded data...

If the data comes from a dynamic soure...You might try:

```
     $('li','#toDB').live('click',function(){ 
 $(this).remove();
})
```

Hope that Works....